# Setting editing range in Vim

Tags: vim, range

Is there a way to set the editing range for a file in Vim so that it will apply to any subsequent command?  I'm about to do some major refactoring of a function and I would like to limit all of my changes (substitutions in this case) to just that function.  In the past I've just copied the function to a new buffer, made the changes and copied it back to the main file, but I'm hoping there is a more clever way.

I know I can set a mark at the start and end of the function and use the marks for the range of the substitute command and I know I can use visual mode to select the range of lines, do something, use gv to reselect and then do the next command, but both of these methods rely on me remembering to specify the range before each command.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: If your function uses braces, you can use `$<Shift>v%` to select the entire function at either the start or the end brace.

Comment: I just know mark & visual selection too, waiting for another elegant method.

Comment: @tandu If vim was compiled with +textobjects, you can more easily select the entire function that the cursor is in with `va{`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a cool trick with folds:

1. Fold your whole function.
2. Perform a substitution, `:s/foo/bar/c<Enter>`, note the `c` flag for "confirmation", it's vital when doing refactoring in Vim. The substitution will be applied to every line *in* the fold. AFAIK, you can run any Ex command that way but I've never used this trick with anything else than `:s` and `:g`/`:v`.
3. Hit `y/n` to accept/reject each substitution.
4. After you accepted/rejected the last substitution the fold goes back instantly to its "closed" state: you don't have to type a range for the next substitution.
5. `GOTO 2`

Comment: Wow, that is a neat trick.  I was never really a fan of folds, but this certainly does what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming vim was compiled with +textobjects, you can select the function as a block.  So perhaps you are looking for:

```
va{:s/foo/bar
```

To replace foo with bar only in the current {} bracketed function.  If your functions are not delimted by braces, you could write a function to select the range according to some syntax rules, but perhaps this is good enough for your needs.

Comment: I am actually aware of that method as well (but don't use it nearly as much as I should).  The problem with this solution is that it still relies on me having to remember to type va{ before each command.  Ideally, I would be able to set the range once and then use something like %s for every subsequent command.  Also, va{ depends on my current cursor position, so if I'm currently within an if-statement it will only select that block and I'd have to hit a{ a few more times to get the entire function.

Answer (score 0):

Use Narow Region Plugin of vim [http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) put them on your vim folder and use like this:

`:[range]NR`

See this page: https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn